# How to query arrays in bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

schema in bigquery
field: items
type: string

Value in table in items field is stored as string
`{"data": [{"id": "1234", "plan": {"sub_id": "567", "metadata": {"currentlySelling": "true", "custom_attributes": "{\"shipping\": true,\"productLimit\":10}", "Features": "[\"10 products\", \"Online support\"]"}, "name": "Personal", "object": "plan"}, "quantity": 1}], "has_more": false}`

Two Questions 1) How can i query within array eg: where shipping is true or where one of the features is "Online support" 2) The reason I had to store the data as string because "custom_attributes" value can change. Is there a better way to store data in bigquery when value of one of the nested key can change?

Comment: you should clarify the actual schema of your table! also - what have you tried so far? Please edit your question to show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You can also read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your query would be something like this:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT game
FROM YourTable
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(participant) WHERE name = 'sam');
```

This returns all of the games where `'sam'` was a participant. Here is a self-contained example:

```
#standardSQL
WITH YourTable AS (
  SELECT 'A' AS game, ARRAY<STRUCT<name STRING, age INT64>>[('sam', 12), ('tony', 12), ('julia', 12)] AS participant UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B', ARRAY<STRUCT<name STRING, age INT64>>[('sam', 12), ('max', 12), ('jacob', 12)] UNION ALL
  SELECT 'C', ARRAY<STRUCT<name STRING, age INT64>>[('sam', 12), ('max', 12), ('julia', 12)]
)
SELECT game
FROM YourTable
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(participant) WHERE name = 'sam');
```

If you wanted to pivot the data to have a column for each participant, you could use a query like this:

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION WasParticipant(
    p_name STRING, participant ARRAY<STRUCT<name STRING, age INT64>>) AS (
  EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(participant) WHERE name = p_name)
);

WITH YourTable AS (
  SELECT 'A' AS game, ARRAY<STRUCT<name STRING, age INT64>>[('sam', 12), ('tony', 12), ('julia', 12)] AS participant UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B', ARRAY<STRUCT<name STRING, age INT64>>[('sam', 12), ('max', 12), ('jacob', 12)] UNION ALL
  SELECT 'C', ARRAY<STRUCT<name STRING, age INT64>>[('sam', 12), ('max', 12), ('julia', 12)]
)
SELECT
  ARRAY_AGG(IF(WasParticipant('sam', participant), game, NULL) IGNORE NULLS) AS sams_games,
  ARRAY_AGG(IF(WasParticipant('tony', participant), game, NULL) IGNORE NULLS) AS tonys_games,
  ARRAY_AGG(IF(WasParticipant('julia', participant), game, NULL) IGNORE NULLS) AS julias_games,
  ARRAY_AGG(IF(WasParticipant('max', participant), game, NULL) IGNORE NULLS) AS maxs_games
FROM YourTable;
```

This returns an array with games played for each participant.

Comment: The data is stored as a string. The above would work if the data is stored as repeated.
`Error: Values referenced in UNNEST must be arrays. UNNEST contains expression of type STRING at [2:36]`

Comment: So `participant` is a string that looks like `'[{"name":"sam","age": 12},{"name":"tony","age": 12},{"name":"julia","age": 12}]`'? It would be better to have your table schema match the data and to use a REPEATED RECORD field for `participant`.

Comment: Elliot, I wanted to do what you said which is match the schema with the data. The reason I was not able to do it because I have some dictionary items eg: custom_attributes that can change so I ended up sticking everything into string column so I don't have to worry about new key/value pairs being added to the custom attributes. I am going to post my table schema and actual data as Mikhail suggested.